# Can a planar shepherd take on the Special Qualities of a pit fiend?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, prestige-class, wild-shape

Does a Druid 8/Planar Shepherd 10 who uses Wild Shape to become a pit fiend take on Special Qualities like

- DR 15/good-and-silver
- Darkvision 60 ft.
- See in darkness
- Immunity to fire and poison
- Resistance to acid 10 and cold 10
- Regeneration 5
- SR 32
- Telepathy 100 ft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, at the 9th level of the planar shepherd class, you gain the following:

> you become able to use wild shape to change into an elemental or outsider native to your chosen plane, although it costs two of your daily uses of wild shape to do so. For example, if you chose the plane of Mabar, you could become a barghest. In addition to the normal effects of wild shape, you gain all the elemental or outsider's extraordinary, supernatural, and spell-like abilities.

Since this is explicitly an extension of Wild Shape, we look to its rules:

> [Wild Shape] functions like the alternate form special ability, except as noted here.

And Alternate Form’s rules include this:

> The creature retains the special qualities of its original form. It does not gain any special qualities of its new form.

So by default, special qualities are not included, however the planar shepherd explicitly gives you all extraordinary, spell-like, and supernatural abilities, even if they are special qualities.

However, note that not all abilities fall under one of those three categories: there are also [natural abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#naturalAbilities). Natural abilities are those things that are not explicitly indicated to be extraordinary, spell-like, or supernatural, and therefore if a special quality is not **explicitly** one of those three, it is a natural ability and you don’t get it.

Therefore:

- DR 15/good-and-silver – Neither the pit fiend description nor the damage reduction description mentions a type, but the glossary in the *Monster Manual* states that damage reduction is extraordinary. There would be some legalistic quibbles on this if we were very strict, but ultimately DR really *should be* Ex. So, accepting the glossary, you **do** get this.
- Darkvision 60 ft. – Not mentioned by the pit fiend description, but the [darkvision description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#darkvision) states this is extraordinary, so you **do** get this.
- See in Darkness – This ability is explicitly Supernatural, as noted by the “(Su)” in its description. You **do** get this.
- Immunity to fire and poison – No explicit type, you do **not** get this.
- Resistance to acid 10 and cold 10 – The [resistance to energy description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#resistanceToEnergy) states that it is “(usually extraordinary)” – and the pit fiend description doesn’t say. I’d call that good enough and say you **do** get this.
- Regeneration 5 – Explicitly (Ex), you **do** get this.
- SR 32 – Not specifically stated in the pit fiend’s description, but the [spell resistance description itself](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance) states that SR is extraordinary: you **do** get this.
- Telepath 100 ft. – Similar situation to DR, neither the pit fiend description nor the telepathy description defines a type for this, but the*Monster Manual* glossary says telepathy is supernatural, which really is what you would expect, so you **do** get this.

Please note that the planar shepherd is one of the most powerful prestige classes in the game, a dramatic increase in power to what is already one of the most powerful bases classes in the game. While it is kind of ridiculous to get legalistic about natural versus extraordinary abilities (and really obnoxious to check every ability), I think it really is important to definitely not give the class any extras.